# how to initiate bean using component&value annotation?

Tags: java, spring

I tried injecting a value from application.yml to a field called 'PROJECT_ID'. However, the following Main class returns only null values.

Can someone tell me how to initiate spring bean using both value and component annotations? The purpose of this is to use the class method(googleTrans) inside Main. Thanks

```java
@Component
public class TestTranslator {

    // API key field
    @Value("${project.id}")
    private String PROJECT_ID;
    
    @Autowired
    public TestTranslator(@Value("${project.id}") String PROJECT_ID) {
        this.PROJECT_ID = PROJECT_ID;
  
        System.out.println(this.PROJECT_ID);
    }

    // translation method 
    public String googleTrans(String text, String sourceLang, String targetLang) { 
        try (TranslationServiceClient client = TranslationServiceClient.create()) {

            LocationName parent = LocationName.of(PROJECT_ID, "global");
            TranslateTextRequest request =
                    TranslateTextRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setParent(parent.toString())
                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                            .setTargetLanguageCode(targetLang)
                            .addContents(text)
                            .build();

            TranslateTextResponse response = client.translateText(request);

            for (Translation translation : response.getTranslationsList()) {
                transResult = translation.getTranslatedText();
            }

        }  catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestTranslatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestTranslator.class);
        OrlaTranslator orlaTranslator = context.getBean("testTranslator", TestTranslator.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you start TestTranslatorApplication in wrong way. Please change your main class to:

**TestTranslatorApplication.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestTranslatorApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TestTranslatorApplication.class, args);
        TestTranslator testTranslator = context.getBean(TestTranslator.class);
        testTranslator.googleTrans("sameple", "en", "ko");
    }
}
```

and a tip here: You can either inject property by adding annotation on the `PROJECT_ID` filed, or as a constructor parameter. I prefer to inject through constructor.

**TestTranslator.java**

```java
private final String PROJECT_ID;

@Autowired
public TestTranslator(@Value("${project.id}") String projectId) {
    this.PROJECT_ID = projectId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. My another question is how can I call the googleTrans method of the TestTranslator class inside Main?

Comment: Do you mean pass the `args` of  `main`  to  `googleTrans` , such as `orlaTranslator.googleTrans(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2])` ?

Comment: I meant to use project.id from application.yml file while calling the googleTrans method. I tried initializing an object like below but the project.id value was changed.

`TestTranslator test = new TestTranslator("1"); 
 test.googleTrans("sameple", "en", "ko");`

Comment: @gwgaeh2  OK, I have updated `main` in my answer, please check it.